# two textbox intersect each line vbcrlf

Tags: vb.net

Textbox1.Lines =

```
2
4
11
13
19
21
```

Textbox2.Lines =

```
3
5
14
17
26
29
```

In output (Textbox3.text) I want the following issue:

```
2 3
4 5
11 14
13 17
19 26
21 29
```

so how do I get this to work?

```
Dim linesx() As String = TxtStringNumP1.Lines
        Dim linesy() As String = TxtStringNumP2.Lines
        For x As Integer = 1 To linesx.Length - 1
            For y As Integer = 1 To linesx.Length - 1
                Dim strWords1 = linesx(y).Split(",")
                Dim strWords2 = linesy(y).Split(",")
                TextBoxO1.Text &= Val(strWords1(0)) + vbCrLf + Val(strWords2(0) & vbNewLine)
            Next
        Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `vbCrLf` as you don't want a new line between the first value & the second. Then, you also don't want a second loop, otherwise you are looping through the values multiple times. You also don't need to split the values by commas if they aren't going to contain commas

Finally, the value needs to be appended to the text already in `TextBox01` otherwise its value is just being replaced. The `TextBox01.Clear()` ensures that it is empty to begin with.

```
    TextBox01.Clear()

    Dim linesx() As String = TxtStringNumP1.Lines
    Dim linesy() As String = TxtStringNumP2.Lines

    For x As Integer = 0 To linesx.Length - 1
        Dim strWords1 As String = linesx(x)
        Dim strWords2 As String = linesy(x)

        TextBoxO1.Text = TextBoxO1.Text & strWords1 & " " & strWords2 & vbCrLf
    Next
```

The above code assumes both text boxes will have the same amount of lines. If this isn't the case, you will need to check that a line exists before trying to assign it to one of your `strWords` variables. You will also need to loop to the larger of the 2 `Lines.Length`

Comment: No worries, glad to help.